# Why does Android SELinux policy prohibit the SIOCOUTQNSD ioctl() command?

Tags: android, tcp, ioctl, selinux

It seems that [Android's SELinux policies block](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/ioctl_macros#26) the [`SIOCOUTQNSD`](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/239843/) `ioctl()` command.

I can guess why many of the other blocked commands are on the list, but I wonder what the rationale is for this one.  `SIOCOUTQNSD` simply returns the amount of unsent data (only) in a TCP socket's send queue.

A similar command, `SIOCOUTQ`, returns the sum of both the *unsent and unacked* data in a TCP socket's send queue, and is explicitly allowed (via its alias, [`TIOCOUTQ`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/ioctl_macros#46)).